# Are there objects with no prototypes in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was told all objects need to have a prototype, however it seems like one can be created with null

```
var obj= Object.create(null);
```

so is the above object prototype-less or does it have some unaccessible native object as its prototype, does null not mean it doesn't have a prototype but simply that it doesn't have an author created prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't have a prototype (or alternatively, the prototype is `null`). There are no properties whatsoever accessible from an object created with `Object.prototype(null)`.

Observe that the result of `Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.create(null))` is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

All objects have an internal [[Prototype]] slot, which can be either `null` or another object.

Some examples of objects whose [[Prototype]] is `null` are `Object.prototype` and `Object.create(null)` indeed.

> [**9.1 Ordinary Object Internal Methods and Internal Slots**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots)
>
> All ordinary objects have an [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) called [[Prototype]].
>   The value of this [internal slot](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots) is either **null** or an object
>   and is used for implementing inheritance. Data properties of the
>   [[Prototype]] object are inherited (are visible as properties of the
>   child object) for the purposes of get access, but not for set access.
>   Accessor properties are inherited for both get access and set access.